# Visual Studio 2010 debugger asks for CD

Tags: visual-studio-2010

It seems that, since this afternoon, the VS2010 debugger will occasionally start checking for a CD when started. It produces a dialog box that I have to cancel several times before finally being able to close the editor and restart it. Two or three hours pass and the problem returns.

So, aside from reinstalling everything, what else could I do?

Comment: The entirety of the single copy it was distributed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that something weird happened when I installed VS2012 RC. Removing VS2102 and reinstalling VS2010 solves the problem.